# how to detect adjacent lines of the same color to detect the damaged area using python?

Tags: python, jpeg, pixel

I am writing a script to find damaged areas of the image based on scanning through the lines of pixels. My idea is to go line by line and compare all the pixel values if they have the same value then save the number of lines and colors. Then check if the lines of the same color are adjacent. But I checked with some damaged images it did not detect. Can you give me suggestions or advice to fix my script? Many thanks

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
path =  "D://python/Check_file/folderA/S165/S165333_1417x952.jpg"
im = Image.open(path).convert('L')
im_array = np.array(im)

width, height = im.size
print(height, width)
a=[]
flag=0

for i in range(0, height):#check for each row
    flag=0
    pix1=im_array[i][0]#color values at the beginning of the line
    
    for j in range(1, width):
        if im_array[i][j] == pix1:
            #check if the remaining colors in the line are the same as the first color of the line
            flag+=1
    if flag==(width-1):#condition that the colors in the line have the same value
        a.append([i,im_array[i][j]])

nb_row=[]
print(len(a))
for i in range(0,len(a)-1):
    if( a[i][1]==a[i+1][1]):
        nb_row.append(a[i][0])
if len(nb_row)>=2:
    print("corrupted")
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this `tr` and `n`. Please also add the image you are trying to repair. Also all the comments seem to have been removed from your code?

Comment: oh sorry, I just revised the tags. [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HB7_D40wqpVeczuTelgIiUXVD5NIQwQM/view?usp=sharing] This is a damaging image to test

Comment: I have edited the tags. I am a newcomer to python so there are many things that I do not fully understand. Can you see the code and give me hint or advice? Thanks so much!!!

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you hope to do, but maybe look at checking the variance across the image (axis=1) https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html If the variance is zero, the pixels are constant along that scanline.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried and also gave the same results as my algorithm. But it still hasn't detected all the corrupted images